# マイレポートのエクスポートについて

Tags: pdf, apple

アナリティクスで、マイレポートをエクスポートし、PDFを開いた際、データが途中で切れてしまい、全部の内容がPDFに表示されません。

google クローム,safari,firefox どのブラウザでも同じようになります。

appleのimacを使用していますが、この不具合の原因は何が考えられますか？
6/1にエクスポートした際は問題なくダウンロード＆出力できましたが、7/2はできず、本日も正しくエクスポートできませんでした。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 単純にデータが多過ぎて途切れている可能性はないですか？

Comment: @user29544 さん、「アナリティクス」というだけではどのサービスをご利用してらっしゃるのかよく分かりません。Google アナリティクスでしょうか？